# Using gdalwarp when source SRS is unclear

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal

I have used `gdal_translate` to translate SRTM data from the NetCDF format to a GeoTIFF. My next step is to use `gdalwarp` to reproject this GeoTIFF, but I'm missing the SRS information on the original NetCDF file. I'm assuming I need to specify the source SRS to `gdalwarp` in order to get an accurate reprojection. Is that the case or could there be enough information available for GDAL to reproject accurately? If I do need the original SRS, how might I find or deduce that?

This is the output from `gdalinfo` on the NetCDF file:

```
Driver: netCDF/Network Common Data Format
Files: SRTM1.nc
Size is 86400, 43200
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (-180.000000000000000,90.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.004166666666667,-0.004166666666667)
Metadata:
  lat#actual_range={-90,90}
  lat#axis=Y
  lat#long_name=latitude
  lat#standard_name=latitude
  lat#units=degrees_north
  lon#actual_range={-180,180}
  lon#axis=X
  lon#long_name=longitude
  lon#standard_name=longitude
  lon#units=degrees_east
  NC_GLOBAL#Conventions=CF-1.7
  NC_GLOBAL#GMT_version=6.0.0 [64-bit]
  NC_GLOBAL#history=grdmath SRTM1_land_masked.nc debug/polished.unmasked.grd AND = SRTM1.nc
  NC_GLOBAL#node_offset=1
  NC_GLOBAL#title=Produced by grdmath
  z#actual_range={-10997.708984375,8627}
  z#long_name=z
  z#_FillValue=nan
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-180.0000000,  90.0000000) 
Lower Left  (-180.0000000, -90.0000000) 
Upper Right ( 180.0000000,  90.0000000) 
Lower Right ( 180.0000000, -90.0000000) 
Center      (   0.0000000,   0.0000000) 
Band 1 Block=86400x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=nan
  Metadata:
    actual_range={-10997.708984375,8627}
    long_name=z
    NETCDF_VARNAME=z
    _FillValue=nan
```

As you can see, there is no coordinate system defined. I used the following command to create the GeoTIFF:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff netCDF:"SRTM1.nc" temp.tif
```

The `gdalinfo` output from that is:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: temp.tif
Size is 86400, 43200
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (-180.000000000000000,90.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.004166666666667,-0.004166666666667)
Metadata:
  lat#actual_range={-90,90}
  lat#axis=Y
  lat#long_name=latitude
  lat#standard_name=latitude
  lat#units=degrees_north
  lon#actual_range={-180,180}
  lon#axis=X
  lon#long_name=longitude
  lon#standard_name=longitude
  lon#units=degrees_east
  NC_GLOBAL#Conventions=CF-1.7
  NC_GLOBAL#GMT_version=6.0.0 [64-bit]
  NC_GLOBAL#history=grdmath SRTM1.nc debug/polished.unmasked.grd AND = SRTM1.nc
  NC_GLOBAL#node_offset=1
  NC_GLOBAL#title=Produced by grdmath
  z#actual_range={-10997.708984375,8627}
  z#long_name=z
  z#_FillValue=nan
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-180.0000000,  90.0000000) 
Lower Left  (-180.0000000, -90.0000000) 
Upper Right ( 180.0000000,  90.0000000) 
Lower Right ( 180.0000000, -90.0000000) 
Center      (   0.0000000,   0.0000000) 
Band 1 Block=86400x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=nan
  Metadata:
    actual_range={-10997.708984375,8627}
    long_name=z
    NETCDF_VARNAME=z
    _FillValue=nan
```

**UPDATE**

I assigned EPSG:4326 to the original NetCDF file as suggested by @user30184
when translating:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_srs epsg:4326 netCDF:"SRTM1.nc” temp.tif
```

Here is the output of `gdalinfo` for that file:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: temp.tif
Size is 86400, 43200
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-180.000000000000000,90.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.004166666666667,-0.004166666666667)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  lat#actual_range={-90,90}
  lat#axis=Y
  lat#long_name=latitude
  lat#standard_name=latitude
  lat#units=degrees_north
  lon#actual_range={-180,180}
  lon#axis=X
  lon#long_name=longitude
  lon#standard_name=longitude
  lon#units=degrees_east
  NC_GLOBAL#Conventions=CF-1.7
  NC_GLOBAL#GMT_version=6.0.0 [64-bit]
  NC_GLOBAL#history=grdmath SRTM1_land_masked.nc debug/polished.unmasked.grd AND = SRTM1.nc
  NC_GLOBAL#node_offset=1
  NC_GLOBAL#title=Produced by grdmath
  z#actual_range={-10997.708984375,8627}
  z#long_name=z
  z#_FillValue=nan
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-180.0000000,  90.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 90d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  (-180.0000000, -90.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 90d 0' 0.00"S)
Upper Right ( 180.0000000,  90.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"E, 90d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Right ( 180.0000000, -90.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"E, 90d 0' 0.00"S)
Center      (   0.0000000,   0.0000000) (  0d 0' 0.01"E,  0d 0' 0.01"N)
Band 1 Block=86400x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=nan
  Metadata:
    actual_range={-10997.708984375,8627}
    long_name=z
    NETCDF_VARNAME=z
    _FillValue=nan
```

Visually, it looked not unexpected:

[image]

However when I applied:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 -r bilinear temp.tif warp1.tif
```

the image was not square as I expected:

[image]

Running `gdalinfo`on that file gave:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: warp1.tif
Size is 58273, 77042
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["X",EAST],
    AXIS["Y",NORTH],
    EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs"],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
Origin = (-20037508.342789247632027,26491625.382435433566570)
Pixel Size = (687.704979247093434,-687.716780883887168)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  lat#actual_range={-90,90}
  lat#axis=Y
  lat#long_name=latitude
  lat#standard_name=latitude
  lat#units=degrees_north
  lon#actual_range={-180,180}
  lon#axis=X
  lon#long_name=longitude
  lon#standard_name=longitude
  lon#units=degrees_east
  NC_GLOBAL#Conventions=CF-1.7
  NC_GLOBAL#GMT_version=6.0.0 [64-bit]
  NC_GLOBAL#history=grdmath SRTM1_land_masked.nc debug/polished.unmasked.grd AND = SRTM1.nc
  NC_GLOBAL#node_offset=1
  NC_GLOBAL#title=Produced by grdmath
  z#actual_range={-10997.708984375,8627}
  z#long_name=z
  z#_FillValue=nan
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-20037508.343,26491625.382) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 88d12' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  (-20037508.343,-26491450.850) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 88d11'59.82"S)
Upper Right (20037123.913,26491625.382) (179d59'47.57"E, 88d12' 0.00"N)
Lower Right (20037123.913,-26491450.850) (179d59'47.57"E, 88d11'59.82"S)
Center      (    -192.215,      87.266) (  0d 0' 6.22"W,  0d 0' 2.82"N)
Band 1 Block=58273x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=nan
  Metadata:
    actual_range={-10997.708984375,8627}
    long_name=z
    NETCDF_VARNAME=z
    _FillValue=nan
```

The corner coordinates here don't make sense for EPSG:3857.

Comment: You can use gdal_translate with `-a_srs` and assign a srs if you know what it is. In this case EPSG:4326 is probably a good guess. If you want to warp an image then gdalwarp needs both source and targer srs. If you do not give them at all then gdalwarp does about the same as gdal_translate.

Comment: Looking at the metadata of the original NetCDF file, I see that the axes are in longitude and latitude, and the NC_GLOBAL#Conventions=CF-1.7. I looked up the latitude-longitude grid mapping in the NetCDF CF conventions (http://cfconventions.org/Data/cf-conventions/cf-conventions-1.7/cf-conventions.html#_latitude_longitude), but that still doesn't help me get an EPSG or proj value.

Comment: It is undefined what happens near the poles if you convert image that covers the whole world (-180,-90 - 180,90) into EPSG:3857. See http://epsg.io/3857 `Area of use: World between 85.06°S and 85.06°N.` Check with some reference data if the conversion happens to be right within the valid area.

Comment: I'm surprised that gdal didn't handle the poles as it typically does when reprojecting to web mercator. This makes me wonder if something else is wrong, like I've got the projection wrong with the original nc file, for instance.

Comment: Do you have sample data to show that typical situation? Web mercator should really clip all data beyound 85.06 degrees S/N.

Comment: I reprojected to EPSG:3857 with the correct EPSG:3857 extent in meters:
`gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857 -r bilinear -te -20037508.34 -20037508.34 20037508.34 20037508.34 temp.tif warp1.tif` and got what appears to be a correct EPSG: 3857 image. So, is the bottom line that the NetCDF file could be assigned any projection that uses degrees longitude as the x values and degrees latitude as the y values?

Comment: I do not know NetCDF but in this case I would say yes. The information that is stored into metadata and that gdalinfo reports as text is easy to interpret even GDAL does not recognize the CRS automatically.